# How do i play a track with a custom id in react-native?(react-native-track)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I can run music from my data file, but it automatically switches to the next. How can I prevent this?

```js
TrackPlayer.setupPlayer().then(async() => {
        console.log("player Ready");
        await TrackPlayer.add(songs);
        TrackPlayer.play();
    });
```

2 examples from my data file:

```js
const songs = [
    {
      title: "death bed",
      artist: "Powfu",
      image: require("./img/a.png"),
      id: "1",
      url:require("../assets/track/animals/lion.mp3"),
    },
    {
      title: "bad liar",
      artist: "Imagine Dragons",
      image: require("./img/b.png"),
      id: "2",
      url:require("../assets/track/animals/bird.mp3"),
    },
```